# Application to monitor use of applications?

Tags: windows, monitoring, migration

To make it easier to migrate users from XP to Windows 7 or 8, I'd like to let an application run for several days to list applications that people use, so I know which ones are really important to them. Then, I'll have to find how to export data + install and reconfigure each application in their home.

I know about SysInternal/MS' [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) but I'd rather something lighter and less intrusive. Is there a lighter alternative that would run in the background?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Does this mean that applications that aren't used often enough will be removed from that user's client during the migration?

Comment: Sometimes the best tools for the job are the tools you already know about.